# Is there an Iphone app <-> UID correlation?

Tags: iphone, ios4

Android maps each app to it's own UID. I was just curious if the iPhone does something similar.

To avoid confusion with another post, I'm referring to UNIX User ID here.
One more note on this. The way to check is, is to open up a terminal app and get a shell on the phone ( I'm assuming iPhone has one). Once you have the shell run the "ps" command. I just want to know if the user ids of the apps are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS's sandboxing doesn't work the same way Android's does. Apps all run as the user "mobile". If you're interested in how the sandboxing actually works, check out the Mac OS X documentation for the (optional) sandbox available to Mac apps—I'm pretty sure they're the same thing.

Comment: thanks! Do you happen to have a reference for that? Thats kind of what I suspected.

Comment: [App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is metadata in each iPhone app's .ipa file that contains information related to the purchaser's iTunes account user ID.  However this iTunes account is not related to any OS user account on the device on which the app is run.

Comment: OK but on the phone, if you run "ps" from the terminal. Will app A have the same userid as app B? In android, they will have seperate uids.

Answer (score 0):

iOS does allow you to call `getuid()`, `getgid()` and friends. But they always return 501, if I recall correctly.

I don't recall seeing a call that allows you to fetch a 16-byte UUID created by the OS during install (similar to what Noah suggested). I think the closest thing is the identifier `com.example.myproduct`.